# Python - Apply function for filling N/A in groups of Group by

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataset with missing values in 2 columns and I would like to fill it by values in previous rows on the last previous date.
So, there are `Weight` and `Height` should be filled with the values from another row based on the last date for predefined `Category` and in reference to `WorkerID` (predefined in previous filled rows), for example:

Data Example:

```
Ind  Date       WorkerID  Category   Weight   Height   Kind_eat
1    31/12/17    E145-46     cat      2.35      0.6       1  
2    01/09/18    M147-50     cat      4.78      0.8       2
3    27/05/18    K178-56     dog      7.03      0.75      3
4    09/02/18    T106-20     mouse    NaN       NaN       1
5    18/03/19    M147-50     cat      NaN       NaN       2
6    25/03/19    K178-56     dog      NaN       NaN       3
7    04/01/17    T106-20     mouse    0.75      0.15      4
8    01/04/19    T156-10     dog      6.99      0.13      4
```

So,  `NaN` of `Weight` and `Height` columns should be filled based on the `Weight`,`Height` columns in reference to non `NaN` values on the last available date which is before actual value in `Date`.

For example,

```
5    18/03/19    M147-50     cat      NaN       NaN       2
```

should be filled by `Weight` and `Height` from `line2`:

```
5    18/03/19    M147-50     cat      4.78      0.8       2
```

I tried to do it by `group-by` and `fillna` method for `group`, but it doesn't fill anything.

```
df.groupby(['Date','WorkerID'], as_index = False).apply(lambda group: group.ffill())
```

also I tried to use: 
`df.groupby(['Date','WorkedID']).ffill().reindex(df.columns, axis=1)`

Actual result is: - no correct filling for NaN

```
Ind  Date       WorkerID  Category   Weight   Height   Kind_eat
1    31/12/17    E145-46     cat      2.35      0.6       1  
2    01/09/18    M147-50     cat      4.78      0.8       2
3    27/05/18    K178-56     dog      7.03      0.75      3
4    09/02/18    T106-20     mouse    NaN       NaN       1
5    18/03/19    M147-50     cat      NaN       NaN       2
6    25/03/19    K178-56     dog      NaN       NaN       3
7    04/01/17    T106-20     mouse    0.75      0.15      4
8    01/04/19    T156-10     dog      6.99      0.13      4
```

Expected result should be:

```
Ind  Date       WorkerID  Category   Weight   Height   Kind_eat
1    31/12/17    E145-46     cat      2.35      0.6       1  
2    01/09/18    M147-50     cat      4.78      0.8       2
3    27/05/18    K178-56     dog      7.03      0.75      3
4    09/02/18    T106-20     mouse    0.75      0.15      1
5    18/03/19    M147-50     cat      4.78      0.8       2
6    25/03/19    K178-56     dog      7.03      0.75      3
7    04/01/17    T106-20     mouse    0.75      0.15      4
8    01/04/19    T156-10     dog      6.99      0.13      4
```

I'd appreciate for any idea. Thanks)

Comment: I think your `line2` described as `5    18/03/19    M147-50     cat      4.78      0.8       2` should be `2    01/09/18    M147-50     cat      4.78      0.8       2`, am I right?

Comment: @SzymonMaszke, no, date should be saved as in line 5: ```18/03/19```, only NaNs from ```Weight``` and ```Height``` columns should be replaced from line 2.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant, though it looks a little confusing, thanks for clarification

Comment: @SzymonMaszke, that's why I don't have any new idea about how it could be fixed.

Comment: @Cindy can you please try: df.sort_values('Date').fillna(method='ffill').sort_values('Ind')

Comment: @VasilisD, Thank you for your idea. It filled ```NaN``` values for ```mouse``` category from 3 line instead of line7. So, ```WorkerID``` and ```Category``` should be saved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to convert `Date`  to `datetime` first.

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

And use `sort_values` by `Date` and `groupby` with `['WorkerID', 'Category']` then `ffill`.

```
df = df.sort_values('Date').groupby(['WorkerID', 'Category']).ffill().sort_index()

df
    WorkerID Category       Date  Weight  Height  Kind_eat
Ind                                                       
1    E145-46      cat 2017-12-31    2.35    0.60         1
2    M147-50      cat 2018-01-09    4.78    0.80         2
3    K178-56      dog 2018-05-27    7.03    0.75         3
4    T106-20    mouse 2018-09-02    0.75    0.15         1
5    M147-50      cat 2019-03-18    4.78    0.80         2
6    K178-56      dog 2019-03-25    7.03    0.75         3
7    T106-20    mouse 2017-04-01    0.75    0.15         4
8    T156-10      dog 2019-01-04    6.99    0.13         4
```